# It doesn't look like the return key is working on my method

Tags: swift, function, uitextfield

I'm working on a program in Swift that is practically like a mini-test (if you are familiar with MVC, the Model holds all the information, questions, answers, etc.) However, I am unable to get my program's textbox to respond to return on the virtual keyboard in iOS. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


        model.recordAnswer(textField.text!)
        numCorrect = model.numOfCorrectAnswers
        numWrong = model.numOfIncorrectAnswers
        txtViewQuestionStatus.text = "\(model.incorrectItems())\n"
        model.theQuestion++
        if model.hasMoreQuestions == true {
            updateQuestionAndAnswer()
        }
        textField.resignFirstResponder() //hide keyboard
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Is that method called at all? Is the delegate set?

Comment: No, it's not, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: If you're using Interface Builder, just connect the outlet. Or do it programmatically. But the type of question indicates that you should start with a very basic tutorial about iOS programming. Virtually all of them have you covered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the above function is called. If it is not called, then you need to set the delegate of your textField. You can do that as follows:

If `txtViewQuestionStatus` this is your UITextField, in your `viewDidLoad()` method, add the following line:

```
txtViewQuestionStatus.delegate = self
```

If there is error in the above line showing delegate is not set, You need to add `UITextFieldDelegate` in your class. Like :

```
class ViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate>
```